# Build and release package vsts free version for (5 users)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

The feature of VSTS is quite interesting. I am trying to create build and release package using the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav. But I don't see save and queue option in build definition page.

Is it not enabled for free user. If it is available can I get the step by step method to create build and release package in vsts. I do have azure account as well.

[image: image for description]

Comment: It should be available for free user. this is your account? are you have admin permissions?

Comment: Yes I am the owner of that account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please verify you are a member of a group that can edit build definitions? By default Teams are a member of the Contributors group, but that does not give build access.

1)  Go to Project Settings -> Security -> Search for your users and make note of which teams/groups you are a member of.

2)  Go to Pipelines -> Builds -> Select the folder icon -> All Build Pipelines -> Select the ellipsis under All Builds -> Security.

[image]

From there you can check if your group has the appropriate permissions such as "Edit Build Definition", "Queue builds"

If you are lacking the appropriate permissions you'll need to resolve that if you are able to administer your project. Otherwise you'll need to discuss with your admin.